# Check is Parse user is already linked to facebook or twitter

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, twitter, parse-platform

I have set up a few Parse users, I have a button that they can click to link to fb or twitter. I want to check if they are already linked so I can have an alertview which tells the user they are already linked.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse provides a set of [utils](http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFFacebookUtils.html) for this kind of thing, one part of which is:

```
+ (BOOL)isLinkedWithUser:(PFUser *)user
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **PFQuery** for this:

```
id loggedUser = ...; // Get your facebook/twitter user info after clicking login
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"email" equalTo:loggedUser[@"email"]];
[query countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int number, NSError *error) {
    if(number > 0) {
        // The user already exists
    } else {
        // No user exists with the email
    }
}];
```

Source: [Parse.com](https://www.parse.com/questions/is-it-possible-to-login-using-facebook-while-checking-if-the-facebook-users-email-exists-in-a-user-in-parse-and-if-it-does-linking-both)